# Unable to run firebase commands from git bash

Tags: firebase-tools

I am trying to use firebase hosting to host my react app, but I cannot seem to be able to run firebase command on git base. To install firebase I ran `npm install -g firebase-tools`. I have also ensured that `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm` is in the windows environment variables. This is the error that I get each time I run a firebase command

```
C:\Users\ALEX PC\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This typically means there's a problem with the NPM/Node install on your system.

While it *is* possible to troubleshoot it, I recommend [installing the standalone executable version of the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows) to more quickly work around the problem.